# Why doesn't "csrf_protection" work on a clean ExpressionEngine install?

Tags: expressionengine, csrf

So I installed EE for the very first time. Copied the files, created the DB and user, ran the installation, and everything worked great.

Next, I go into my config file and set:

```
$config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;
```

That’s all it takes… now I can’t log into the Control Panel!  I get the “The action you have requested is not allowed.”

What am I doing wrong!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you trying to set that in your config file? I'm pretty sure `csrf_protecton` is a CodeIgniter setting and not properly supported by EE. EE has other built in security measures to avoid CSRF attacks.

Comment: Funny you should say that, as I come from a CodeIgniter background; my first instinct was to turn on `csrf_protection`. So are you saying that I don't have to do anything *extra* to guard my site agains CSRF attacks using ExpressionEngine?

Comment: EE uses a similar (but different) system to protect against CSRF - I'm not familiar with how raw CodeIgniter handles it, but EE uses an XID hidden field in nearly all forms (every form in the CP has it by default), and most front end add-ons I'm aware of opt-in to this as well.

Comment: Also found this which may be useful: http://expressionengine.com/forums/viewthread/199161/